# Making AC current with pin 11

Tags: arduino-uno, analogwrite

I'm trying to make AC current (50Hz) with an Arduino Uno. It seems to be not working (or wrong code).

```
int up;
int down;
int out = 11;
void setup() {
  pinMode(out, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  for (up = 0; up <= 255; up++) {
    analogWrite(out, up);
    delay(1);
  }
  for (down = 255; down >= 0; down--) {
    analogWrite(out, down);
    delay(1);
  }
}
```

**Update:**

1. Now the code above is giving output voltage of 0-5V (getting increased from 0 to 5 and then decreased) not giving a negative cycle (-5V).
2. After setting the minimum delay of 1, the output wave is still half wave rectifier with frequency 2Hz.
3. Without delay LED is blinking so fast I don't know what's its frequency.

How do I make make 50Hz AC current a with negative cycle?

Comment: The UNO doesn't have a DAC. So you need to filter the PWM output to get an analog AC voltage.

Comment: What you have there (apart from your lack of brackets on the `for` which breaks it all) is code for a saw-tooth wave (if you filter it) at 1.95Hz.

Comment: Your code shows a real lack of understanding of the basics of C programming.

Comment: ohhh, i thought arudino analogWrite output is sin wave. After watching this https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/PWM it's seems like arduino gives output only in digital wave.

Comment: It's digital (as in Pulse Width Modulation) but when filtered (low pass filter) it forms an analog voltage. By setting the duty cycle (analogWrite) in the right way you can form one discrete part of an AC waveform. If you want a sine wave then you have to form a sine wave out of discrete values.

Comment: Normally that is done using a look-up table (LUT) since calculating values of `sin` is far too slow on a little 8-bit MCU.

Comment: @Majenko updated the `for` loop and also code. Checked with multimeter on AC it's showing around 5V and on DC it's showing around 2.5V. seems like half AC current at 50Hz is created. now working on low pass filter.

Comment: Your code is still far from correct. There's bits there that aren't wanted, and the bits that are wanted are in the wrong place (and the wrong value, and just plain wrong).

Answer (score 2):

I ran your sketch and this is the output signal:

[image: square wave]

`analogWrite` produce a square wave.

As Majenko said, you have to add a low pass filter to get that sine wave.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not critical on the waveform you can use a transformer where the secondary has a center tap. The primary should have one as well. Tie the input center tap to +12 or whatever is available but DO NOT use the arduino 5 volt pin. Then using two avalanche protected N channel MOSFETs you them to drive the remaining two input leads.  The output will be a pseudo sine wave, far from perfect but it will have the negative excursion you want.This type of circuirity can be found in Switch Mode Power Supplies (SMPS). Note the transformer winding ratio will determine your output voltage. You will need a little dead time between turning one MOSFET off and the Other on.  A single mosfet would work but there would only be two connections to the transformer primary not 3 and the wave form will be a lousy.

Comment: You do realize you're answering a more than 4 year old question, I hope. Your answer would benefit greatly from a schematic.